# Installing (build) matplotlib in mac osx lion

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-lion

I installed pynum and scipy (on osx Lion with python 2.7), but when I tried to build matplotlib

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

I've got these errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Headers/ATSTypes.h:242: error: declaration for parameter ‘FMFontDirectoryFilter’ but no such parameter
src/_macosx.m:5912: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/qw/pr2f7vq91b3c3ngkxrrqplm8zkv09r/T//ccAgEklo.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Could somebody please tell me what is the problem?

P.S.
At first I tried to install it in this way:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib#egg=matplotlib-dev
```

but it does not worked for me

Comment: This isn't a solution, but if you do get really frustrated, you could try installing the [Free Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php), which comes with numpy, scipy, and matplotlib.

Comment: I just tried and it compiles fine for me with python 2.7 and lion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I always find this process more painful than it should be, but I've done it a few times now and I believe that these steps should get you set up:

1. Get Xcode 4.3.2, it's required for some of the later steps.
2. [Download](http://python.org/download/) the latest version of python for OSX from python.org
3. Grab the [Scipy superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/).
4. Uninstall any previous versions of numpy/matplotlib/scipy that you currently have.  That includes doing `cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and moving any numpy/matplotlib/scipy directories or eggs into a temp directory.
5. `cd ~/Downloads`(or wherever you downloaded the superpack script to) and run `sh install_superpack.sh`.  **Answer no** to the question `are you installing from a repository cloned to this machine` or you'll be confused about why the script keeps failing.

That should be it!  You should now be able to boot up the python console and `import numpy, scipy, matplotlib`.

Comment: It's almost worked! Now I'm able to import numpy, scipy, matplotlib, but this code doesnt work well: 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()

It cause error:
 from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY, \
ImportError: No module named dateutil.rrule

Comment: @pupadupa try reinstalling dateutil, you're using python 2 so you need dateutil 1.x instead of 2.x.  dateutil can be found [here](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) so try to find a version that is correct for you.