# python 2.7 not installing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.7

Hi I'm trying to install matplotlib on my mac. I have lion OS X.

my python version is `2.7.1` ( this is what it says when I run it from terminal)

every time I install matplotlib, it promots this error

```
matplotlib 1.1.0 cannot be installed on this disk. matplotlib requires System python 2.7 to install.
```

I'm new to the python world and I need a tool to graph a few things... so a clear explanation is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I've posted a [guide to installing matplotlib on osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183144/installing-build-matplotlib-in-mac-osx-lion/10183340#10183340) a few times now, and my instructions have yet to fail.  Try that and let me know if it doesn't work?

Comment: A more detailed traceback would be helpful.  You should be more specific about what method you're using to install steps you took and what error you're getting.

Comment: @shuzOMGchen hi, I mentioned the error above which is       matplotlib 1.1.0 cannot be installed on this disk. matplotlib requires System python 2.7 to install.                                   I'm just installing it using the the excutable it came with from the following link  http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/       I hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 4):

You are installing a binary package which is going to expect a specific system python. You are better off building from source.

Just try installing it from pip:

```
pip install numpy 
pip install matplotlib
```

If you do not yet have pip, you can install it like this:

```
wget "http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py"
python ez_setup.py
easy_install pip
```

If any of this fails, then follow [@Nolen Royalty's guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183144/installing-build-matplotlib-in-mac-osx-lion/10183340#10183340) that he mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 3):

I've tried installing python in various different ways to get numpy, scipy, and matplotlib to all work together, and its a huge pain.  Your exact version of python will dictate the version of numpy, scipy, and matlplotlib that will work for you.

By far, the easiest solution I have found is to use the pre-built package Enthought.  It takes care of all of those problems with one easy installer.  You might get some additional software installed like mayavi (an interactive 3d plotting tool), but its not too much.

If you are a student (or have ever been one since the dawn of email), you can download the entire Enthought package for free [here](http://www.enthought.com/products/getepd.php). Or you can visit the Enthought home at [www.enthought.com](http://www.enthought.com).  All you have to do is select the academic license and then insert a email that ends in .edu.

I even think there are free trial versions which should solve the issue.  I've never tried any of the trial versions, but even if it is a limited time trial, you should be able to use the trial version, and then see exactly which versions of each package you need to install.  Its a little more roundabout, but it should work.

Comment: Anaconda is also quite good (honestly I immensely prefer Spyder over Enthought's IDE).